# Connection Character Sets в MySQL

Tags: mysql, charset

Здравствуйте! У меня следующий вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю что устанавливая Connection Character Set я фактически определяю Character Set всей бд на время подключения?(я уже пробовал выгружать данные с разными Character Sets и результат был разным)
2. Зачем определять Character Set при создании бд/таблицы если при подключении всё равно можно задать свой, который всё перекрывает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании таблицы, Вы определяете кодировку, в которой хранятся данные.

При создании подключения, Вы определяете кодировку, в которой клиент отправляет данные и в которой он ожидает получить.

Если кодировки таблицы и подключения различаются, то сервер производит конвертацию из одной в другую, что занимает время. Поэтому для максимальной производительности, чтобы избежать лишних конвертаций, эти кодировки должны совпадать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А в документации о конвертации что-нибудь говорится? Я просто не нашел этого

Comment: Уже нашел сам всё